# Java Ellipses Signature for Multiple Parmeters

Tags: java, methods, parameters

Firstly,
I am studying function with new type of signature and body, and in this code, I want to know, what type of object is `values`?  It doesn't appear to be an array of strings based on my observation.
Secondly, is there any method that returns the name of the class a particular object is?  I thought it might be `tostring`, but that returned `Ljava.lang.String;@1540e19d` in the code below.  Don't understand this...

```
static double AddValues(String ... values) {

    double result = 0;
    Object o = values;
    System.out.println("XXXz");
    System.out.println(o.toString());


    for (String value : values)
    {
        double d = Double.parseDouble(value);
        result += d;

    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html) argument, and `values` is treated as a String *array*. Java is hiding the array creation, note., but you can call that method with an array rather than just a list of arguments.

Comment: I believe `L` in the descriptor for a reference type means reference; if it were an array, I'd think it would be `[Ljava.lang.String`.

Comment: Yes, you're right re. that

Comment: @Zymus It *does* return `[Ljava.lang.String`, even when only one value was supplied to the vararg. OP must have thought the bracket an omission or a useless character.

Comment: @Ordous I figured as much. I can't see a way to get that output that OP specified.

Answer (score -1):

`values` is an array of `String`. I'm not sure what observation led you to conclude otherwise. Variadic method parameters in Java collect the arguments into an array, as you can see in the [Java 5 varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) documentation.

To find out the type of an object, use `values.getClass().getName()` (yields `"[Ljava.lang.String;"` indicating an array of `String`). You can use `values.getClass().isArray()` to test whether it is an array and `values.getClass().getComponentType()` to get the type of its elements.

See the [array components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayComponents.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: Could a downvoter indicate what is wrong with my answer? My answer is correct. The type of `values` is in fact `String[]`.